# Java Android - Proper Way to create a Chat/Communication?

Tags: java, android, chat, communication

I were wondering what's the proper way to create a chat/communication software in Java for Android?

I guess it's a Socket (TCP/UDP).

If I do it my own way like using a web calls for PHP with backend scripts why it is not so appropriate way to create a chat? What's the difference between them? Using a calls instead of raw sockets? Does it use more battery or something? I just feel that sometimes it would be more easier to parse a JSON for messages and send data through web calls, but I feel that it's not a proper way to do so and application may have a critical issues like draining a battery or something which will make the project to be discontinued.

I would like to be sure is there any other ways to create a chat, than sockets and do every famous developers use a sockets as primary method for creating a communication software?

Comment: There's a lot of ways. For example - Firebase. https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat. Sockets are very low-level.

Comment: Using a php backend and JSON to move the messages around is perfectly acceptable.  Battery usage and other concerns are not going to be affected in a measurable way by this choice.

Comment: Thank you all about the information. I were first thinking about to create GREAT looking (basic) chat only with some friends list. I still have a lot to learn. Like what's the best way to receive a lightweight pulse to Android that it won't use a lot of traffic to be known about new message that arrives.

Comment: simple udp server/client would work just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The protocol could be **Socket** or others such as **[XMPP](https://xmpp.org/)**

If you prefer using Socket, [SmartFox](http://www.smartfoxserver.com/) might be one of the libraries that you can rely on. Smartfox offers SDK for a number of languages such as C#, Java etc.

Note however, that if you use socket for communication, usually json is **NOT** used, since most of the times, binary objects are used in the socket-based communications, say for example, SmartFox uses ISFSObject, which wraps all the data into a binary object.

Below posts might be useful for you to get started, though it is not written in java, but essentially the workflows are exactly the same.

- [Using SmartFox with C# (I) : Installations and 1st handshaking](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2015/09/14/using-smartfox-with-c-i-installations-and-1st-handshaking/)
- [Using SmartFox with C# (II) : Login and join room](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2015/09/14/using-smartfox-with-c-ii-login-and-join-room/)
- [Using SmartFox with C# (III) : Frequently used functions](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2015/09/14/using-smartfox-with-c-iii-frequently-used-functions/)

Apart from the socket and xmpp appraoches, you can also opt to use **WebRTC**, where there is no such kinds of servers, and peer to peer communication is used. A good tutorial can be found [here](https://github.com/GleasonK/android-webrtc-tutorial).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've built sometimes ago a C# socket chat, but usually I stuck on same issue that the server output doesn't print out the sent message correctly. I have tried to read the message from 0 index, but it still shows me something similar "■■■User: Hello" the squares comes from somewhere and I don't understand why. It can be issue that I don't determine the packet size correctly, but when I start learning more about Sockets and Packets I probably come here and I will post my source that somebody can sort it out what I did wrong. PS. I was trying to use raw packets +ASCII

Comment: You don't have to reinvent the wheels using raw socket in C#. Use smartfox and others off-the-shelf one is more economical and saves you tons of time in debugging, testing and deployment.

Comment: I'm probably checking it out next time I turn my computer on! :)